# Angular Material Table with keyboard navigation - listen to all keydown events except those from the Overlay Components

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-material-table

I'm trying to implement a `MatTable` with **keyboard interaction**, in order to select the rows inside the table.

For the keyboard interaction, I've used `FocusKeyManager` from `Cdk`'s- `a11y` module. Also, the `keydown` event is attached to the host (`mat-table`).

```
this.keyManager = new FocusKeyManager<MatRowFocusableDirective>(
  this.rows
).withHomeAndEnd();


@HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
public onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
 this.keyManager.onKeydown(event);
}
```

At this point, everything works fine.

But I wanted to **extend** the keyboard interaction, similar to the Gmail web app:

- on **any keypress (up/down arrow) inside the document**, I want to start the navigation inside the table:

  ```
  @HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"])
  public onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    this.keyManager.onKeydown(event);
  }
  ```

This works, but, in the app, I also use other Angular Material components that are build upon **CDK Overlays**, like Dialogs, Selects, Bottomsheets, etc.

The issue is that when one of these components is opened, the keyboard interaction within the table is still available.

How can I disable the keyboard interaction within the table when any of the **CDK Overlay** components is opened?

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tspvfu-onnsdk

Comment: Your stackblitz code works good, with the exeception that if you use the Up/Down arrow keys it does not update the activeItemIndex.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

1. Create a service with a `shouldFocusOnKeyboard` property (name it how you want).
2. Use `cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus` or `cdkMonitorElementFocus` to detect when elements outside of your table received focus.
3. On each element you applied the monitoring directive to, use the `cdkFocusChange` event to change the value of `shouldFocusOnKeyboard`.
4. Use the new service to determine whether to pass the `document:keydown` event to the `keyManager` or not.

[Focus monitoring with CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#cdkmonitorelementfocus-and-cdkmonitorsubtreefocus)

Pro Tip:
A better design would probably be to create the `shouldFocusOnKeyboard` as a `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` and pipe it in your event handler.